# Django and phoneGap - How do django templates work with phoneGap?

Tags: django, cordova, django-templates, phonegap-plugins

We're about to develop a web-application using Django and also develop the mobile application for the same using PhoneGap later. So, essentially I would be using the front end pages that I develop using Django for the PhoneGap project as well.

How would Django templates work with PhoneGap? Since PhoneGap takes in only static web pages (in the form of HTML,CSS and JS), what should be done to resolve this issue with Django templates and PhoneGap compliance?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't just compile your Django app into hybrid Apps. PhoneGap wouldn't run or compile any server side code, so you can't use Django templates.

But you can integrate your PhoneGap app to current Django app by using REST API. You can do Ajax request to your Django app.